# Type-safely import TypeScript modules from paths known only at run-time

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a file tree of TypeScript code and assets that I am serving from some arbitrary URL (such as between a CDN and a debug location) - I want to be able to import the root of that module, and allow the rest of the tree to import correctly, exactly when needed (i.e. without having to supply the loading path more than once).

In JavaScript, I could probably do something like this:

```
export class MyModule {
    private dependentModulePromise;

    constructor(rootpath) {
        this.dependentModulePromise = import(rootpath + '/dependentModule');
    }
}
```

If I were to do this in TypeScript, however, I would want it to be as typesafe as possible. Obviously I would need to use a type assertion here for the original dynamic string import, but how can I safely tell TypeScript about the type that I'm loading, without running into name conflicts or synchronously importing the module (which, in something like Webpack, makes it part of the bundle)?

I did try this extension:

```
import * as DependentModule from '/dependentModule';

export class MyModule {
    private dependentModulePromise: Promise<DependentModule>;

    constructor(rootpath) {
        this.dependentModulePromise = import(rootpath + '/dependentModule') as Promise<DependentModule>;
    }
}
```

but I end up with an error telling me that the namespace `DependentModule` cannot be used as a type.

Comment: The problem is with the `import *`.   When you import everything from a file and assign it to a name like `DependentModule`, typescript sees that as a namespace and the individual exports as values on that namespace.  Does `/dependentModule` have a default export?

Comment: @LindaPaiste Does it have to have one? If it does, I could make that work, though I'd prefer to be able to import an arbitrary module if I could.

Comment: To be honest I don’t know if that will actually fix your problem.  I just know that the import * is the source of the current error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something pretty close: if `/dependentModule` has a default export, instead of trying to export a namespace, then it works fine.

```
// Here, dependentModule exports a class
import { default as DependentModule_TYPE_ONLY } from '/dependentModule';

export class MyModule {
    private dependentModulePromise: Promise<new () => DependentModule_TYPE_ONLY>;

    constructor(rootpath) {
        this.dependentModulePromise = import(rootpath + '/dependentModule') as Promise<new () => DependentModule>;
    }
    
    public async doStuffWithDependentModule() {
        const DependentModule = await this.dependentModulePromise;
        const m = new DependentModule();
        // now do typesafe stuff with m
    }

}
```

Obviously, the best route is if this default export implements some interface or type shape found elsewhere, so that the promise can be cast to that instead of as an instance of the class (i.e. if `DependentModule` implements `IInterfaceOfInterest`, then the `import` promise is of type `Promise<new () => IInterfaceOfInterest>`).